# Repeating the action of a function when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to recreate a sample Android app from Treehouse in javascript/jQuery that refreshes an h3 with a new fact every time the "Next Fact" button is pressed and it works but only for the next random fact, then it stops. So how do I get it to refresh with a new fact every time the button is pressed? Here's my js:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  var facts = [
    "Ants stretch when they wake up in the morning.", 
    "Ostriches can run faster than horses.", 
    "Olympic gold medals are actually made mostly of silver.", 
    "You are born with 300 bones; by the time you are an adult you will have 206.", 
    "It takes about 8 minutes for light from the Sun to reach Earth.", 
    "Some bamboo plants can grow almost a meter in just one day.", 
    "The state of Florida is bigger than England.", 
    "Some penguins can leap 2-3 meters out of the water.", 
    "On average, it takes 66 days to form a new habit.", 
    "Mammoths still walked the earth when the Great Pyramid was being built."
   ];

  var fact = facts[Math.round(Math.random() * (facts.length - 1))];

  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#anotherfact").empty();
    $("#anotherfact").append(fact);
    //Fix me
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the fact each time the click handler is clicked:

Move fact into the click function:

```
 $("#button").click(function() {
        var fact = facts[Math.round(Math.random() * (facts.length - 1))];
        $("#anotherfact").empty();
        $("#anotherfact").append(fact);
 });
```

Instead of declaring `fact` once at page load (this is why you always get one fact at the beginning)

Comment: sixty, if this answered your question, please accept as answer

Comment: Thanks. Sorry. I was indisposed this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a fact each time the button is clicked instead of before the event handler is bound.

i.e. move `var fact = facts[Math.round(Math.random() * (facts.length - 1))];` down three lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var fact = facts[Math.round(Math.random() * (facts.length - 1))];
    $("#anotherfact").empty().html(fact);
  });
```

you need to select new fact EACH click !